# Dissecting tetrahedra into similar tetrahedra

Tags: cg.comp-geom

> (i) Does anybody know what is the smallest number $k$ such that there
>   is a tetrahedron T that can be subdivided into $k$ tetrahedra that are
>   similar to T ?

I know $k$ is at most 8 (I know a tetrahedron that can be subdivided into 8 similar tetrahedra), and at least 3 (I can prove no tetrahedron can be subdivided into 2 tetrahedra that are similar to the whole). Does anybody know better lower or upper bounds?

> (ii) What if we require the tetrahedra in the subdivision to have the
>   same size? (Again, I know $3 \leq k \leq 8$)

Answer (score 4):

Hi Herman — since you asked me this at GD, I've found an answer to version (ii) of your question. Jiří Matoušek and Zuzana Safernová have shown that subdivision of a tetrahedron into $k$ tetrahedra that are similar to the original and congruent to each other is possible only when $k$ is a cube (and it is conjectured more strongly that this is possible exactly when $k$ is a power of eight, the case you already know about). See their paper "On the nonexistence of k-reptile tetrahedra", [arXiv:1006.1807](http://arxiv.org/abs/1006.1807).